# Changing cell color if 10 more touching cells have the same value

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel spreadsheet full of X's and O's and I need change the cell color if there are ten or more cells next to each other in any given spot in the entire row.

Example:

XXXXXXOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOXX

XOXXXXOOXXOOXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

OOOXXXXOOOOXXXOOOOOOOOOOO

In the first row, I would need all 17 O's to have their cell color changed because it's 10 or more next to each other. And so on for row 2 and 3...

I'm not sure how to approach this..

*EDIT*
I apologize. I was trying to simplify my request but maybe I should have just put it all out there. I have 14 different variables that can be in the cell. D,FA,FD,FI,I,J,L,M,O,P,T,U,V,X. If any of them besides X and T are next to each other in the same row 10 or more times, I need Interior.Color changed to red.

Again I apologize. New to using stackoverflow.

Comment: Is each X or O in its own cell? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Yes, each X or O are in their own cell.

Comment: I can't figure out how to do it. I was wondering if I should make an X and O range and use Intersect to test. But that would only limit me to the number of X's or O's I put in the test range.

Answer (score 3):

Using Conditonal Formatting instead of vba:

Create a new rule for column A:Y using this formula:

```
=AND(A1<>"",IFERROR(AGGREGATE(15,6,COLUMN(A1:$Y1)/(A1:$Y1=IF(A1="X","O","X")),1),COLUMN($Y1))-IFERROR(AGGREGATE(14,6,COLUMN($A1:A1)/($A1:A1=IF(A1="X","O","X")),1),COLUMN($A1))>=10)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just took a shot at it for fun...

```
Sub XsandOs()

Dim lastrow As Long, lastcol As Long, xcounter As Long, ocounter As Long

lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
lastcol = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, ActiveSheet.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

For i = 1 To lastrow
    For j = 1 To lastcol
        If Cells(i, j).Value = "x" Then
            xcounter = xcounter + 1
            If j = lastcol Then xcounter = 0
            ocounter = 0
            If xcounter = 10 Then
                Range(Cells(i, j - 9), Cells(i, j)).Interior.Color = vbRed
            End If
        ElseIf Cells(i, j).Value = "o" Then
            ocounter = ocounter + 1
            If j = lastcol Then ocounter = 0
            xcounter = 0
            If ocounter = 10 Then
                Range(Cells(i, j - 9), Cells(i, j)).Interior.Color = vbRed
            End If
        End If
    Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

[image: BeforeAfter]

Answer (score 1):

@ScottCraner solution definitely the one to go for, but liked my VBA solution so I'll throw it in the mix.

The code assumes you only have X and O but will colour any repeating values of 10 or more.

```
Public Sub Test()

    Dim rLastCell As Range
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim rFirstCell As Range
    Dim rCurrentCell As Range

    Set rLastCell = LastCell(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1"))

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        'A For Each will step through each cell going across the columns and then down the rows.
        'Just need to reset if the it's the first column and check if the next cell is equal to the previous
        'and reset when it changes.
        For Each rCell In .Range(.Cells(1, 1), rLastCell)
            If rCell.Column = 1 Then
                Set rFirstCell = rCell
            ElseIf rCell.Value <> rFirstCell.Value Then
                If rCell.Column - rFirstCell.Column >= 10 Then
                    rFirstCell.Resize(, rCell.Column - rFirstCell.Column).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                End If
                Set rFirstCell = rCell
            End If
        Next rCell
    End With

End Sub

Public Function LastCell(wrkSht As Worksheet, Optional Col As Long = 0) As Range

    Dim lLastCol As Long, lLastRow As Long

    On Error Resume Next

    With wrkSht
        If Col = 0 Then
            lLastCol = .Cells.Find("*", , , , xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Column
            lLastRow = .Cells.Find("*", , , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
        Else
            lLastCol = .Cells.Find("*", , , , xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Column
            lLastRow = .Columns(Col).Find("*", , , , xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Row
        End If

        If lLastCol = 0 Then lLastCol = 1
        If lLastRow = 0 Then lLastRow = 1

        Set LastCell = wrkSht.Cells(lLastRow, lLastCol)
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

End Function
```